# ASP.net WebForms - Using GetRouteUrl in markup

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-routing

I have been trying to figure out how to use the Routing features with ASP.net 4.0 WebForms.
I added  a route to my route collection:

```
void Application_Start()
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "about-route",
        "about/",
        "~/About.aspx"
    );
}
```

In my master page I tried to do the following:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="asdf" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%= GetRouteUrl("about-route", new {}) %>'>Test</asdf>
```

I got a compiler error: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

What is the proper way to create a route URL in a server control in Web Forms? I also need to include it in the following:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="ROUTE HERE" Text="Home"/>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="ROUTE HERE" Text="About"/>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a special syntax for using routes in markup: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx#Y800

```
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl='<%$RouteUrl:about-route%>' Text="About"></asp:MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

right syntax

```
<a href='<%$RouteUrl:routename=about-route %>' runat="server">Homepage</a>
```

Comment: You *do not* want to use that. It is vulnerable to an XSS attack, e.g.: http://localhost:40000/(A(%22onmouseover=%22alert%60XSS%60%22))/test.aspx