# Asp.net WebForm - Using RouteUrl in Markup

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I try use syntax shown in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326935/asp-net-webforms-using-getrouteurl-in-markup) but I still getting errors like:

> Invalid expression, RouteUrlExpressionBuilder expects a string with
>   format: RouteName=route,Key1=Value1,Key2=Value2.

My route and link are:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("about", "about/", "~/About.aspx");

<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="<%$RouteUrl:about%>">About</asp:HyperLink>
```

Could u tell my what I doing wrong?

Comment: One of my routes looks e.g. like `routes.MapPageRoute(@"01", @"start", @"~/ui/mainwindow/start/index.aspx", true);`. So maybe adding the boolean parameter might help?

Comment: Not rly still have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As error mentioned, we need to have register some thing like this

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
                "about",
                "about/{Name}",
                "~/About.aspx"
            );
```

Then master page should be like:

```
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="<%$RouteUrl:Name=Test %>" Text="About" />
```

Comment: But I have one section "About" on my site and I don't want to give any parameter. 
Somthing like Home / News / Contact / About

Comment: <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="about" Text="About" />  If I use only pure text "about" this working correctly. I don't know why.